# ask for record id on form open (microsoft access 2013)

Tags: forms, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am willing to create a form which upon it's opening, it should prompt the user to enter the record ID it should open on.

the form needs to open the record ID specified upon its launch, not an assigned ID previously, I think it should do the prompting like something the [] do in queries.

any help would be appreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: This sounds like bad design in the first place. Your users shouldn't need to worry about record Ids, let alone have to remember them. Create another form that lets the user select a record from which you open your form.

Comment: thank you, the record ID is the Emp. ID of a company so remembering the ID is not a problem in the first place, but the solution you have suggested should work as well, except it is a two step job and it takes more time. any help on the asked question would be appreciated

Comment: Without knowing more it's really tough to give you specifics.  But generally this sort of thing is done by taking off the form's reordsource and assigning it only after the user puts in a value with said value as the filter.  Research 'Late Binding' over at [Link](www.utteraccess.com) and you will be well on your way.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward.  You can do this either of 2 ways:

Create a form with a Textbox (or Combobox) where the user will enter an ID or select it from a list.  Then create a button called something like btnSubmit.  Behind the button, in code, you would enter something like:

```
sqlRecordSource = "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RecordID = " & Me.MyTextboxName & ""
DoCmd.RunSQL sqlRecordSource
```

The other option you could have is that you create a query, call it qryRecordID, and the SQL would look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE RecordID = [Enter a RecordID]
```

You could then run that query anywhere and not need a separate form with a RecordID textbox, because the query will automatically prompt you for one.